# How to remove text input from form field when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a group of radio buttons and a single text input field. When I click on the text input the radio buttons become unchecked using JavaScript, but when I type something into the form field and then reselect a radio button I can not get the text to be deleted. Here is my code so far, If someone could help me get the text box to clear all input when I select a radio I know im close.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios"   checked>
<label for="radio1">$10</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" >
<label for="radio2">$25</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios"  >
<label for="radio3">$50</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" >
<label for="radio4">$100</label>
<input type="text" id="textInput">
<script>
<!-- to remove radio on text input click-->
$('#textInput').click(function () {
    $.each($('input[type=radio]'), function () {
         $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
});
<!-- to remove text on text radio button click-->
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    $.each($('#textInput'), function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("input");
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove their value using `val()`. `input` isn't an attribute, it's a tag name.

```
$.each($('#textInput'), function () {
    $(this).val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use **.val()**, also you don't need `$.each`

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    $('#textInput').val('');            
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.val("")` to set the text box value to empty.

Try this,

```
$('#textInput').each(function () {
   $(this).val("");
});
```